# Difference of subset sums

Tags: combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $n$. We want to choose some numbers in $[0,1]$ such that the difference between the sums of any two subsets is at least $1/n$. At most how many numbers can we choose (in terms of $n$)?

Suppose we choose $k$ numbers. Then the sum of any subset is in $[0,k]$, and there are $2^k$ subset sums, so by the pigeonhole principle some two differ by at most $k/2^k$. This means $k/2^k>1/n$, or $2^k/k<n$, so $k$ can only be slightly more than $\log_2 n$. Is it possible to prove that $k\leq O(\log n)$?

Comment: Do you mean " the difference ... is *at least* $1/n$"? (Otherwise you can take as many numbers as you want, just requesting that their total sum is smaller than $1/n$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $2^k$ subset sums, all distance at least $1/n$ away of each other. Therefore, the difference between the largest and the smallest of them is at least $(2^k-1)/n$. However, all these subset sums are contained in the interval $[0,k]$. This gives $(2^k-1)/n\le k$, leading to $2^k\le 2kn$ and, as a result, to $$k<(1+o(1))\log_2n.$$

Comment: The trivial estimate is $k≤n$ (every interval of length $1/n$ contains at most one element of your set). Hence, $\log_2k\le\log_2n$. Consequently, taking the logarithms, from $2^k\le 2kn$ you get $k\le 1+2\log_2n<3\log_2n$. Repeating the procedure and using this better estimate for $k$, you get
 $$ k \le 1 + \log_2(3\log_2n) + \log_2n. $$
Is everything clear now?